# Handling compound words (2-grams) using NLTK

Tags: nlp, nltk, tokenize, spacy

I'm trying to identify user similarities by comparing the keywords used in their profile (from a website). For example, `Alice = pizza, music, movies`, `Bob = cooking, guitar, movie` and `Eve = knitting, running, gym`. Ideally, `Alice` and `Bob` are the most similar. I put down some simple code to calculate the similarity. To account for possible plural/singular version of the keywords I use something like:

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
wnl = WordNetLemmatizer()
w1 = ["movies", "movie"] 
tokens = [token.lower() for token in word_tokenize(" ".join(w1))]
lemmatized_words = [wnl.lemmatize(token) for token in tokens]
```

So that, `lemmatized_words = ["movie", "movie"]`. 
Afterwards, I do some pairwise keywords comparison using [`spacy`](https://spacy.io/usage/vectors-similarity), such as:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
t1 = nlp(u"pizza")
t2 = nlp(u"food")
sim = t1.similarity(t2)
```

Now, the problem starts when I have to deal with compound  words such as: `artificial intelligence`, `data science`, `whole food`, etc. By tokenizing, I would simply split those words into 2 (e.g. `artificial` and `intelligence`), but this would affect my similarity measure. What is (would be) the best approach to take into account those type of words?

Comment: To my knowledge, this is a sort of an open problem in computational linguistics. Non-compositional phrases (i.e. compound terms) can be detected over large corpora by n-gram frequency abnormalities (i.e. artificial intelligence would appear more often than any other bi-gram containing artificial xor intelligence, signifying its non-compositional nature). I don't have an answer to your question but I do have a few relevant papers that might interest you.

Comment: Check this out: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/phrases.html

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to achieve this. One way would be to create the embeddings (vectors) yourself. This would have two advantages: first, you would be able to use bi-, tri-, and beyond (n-) grams as your tokens, and secondly, you are able to define the space that is best suited for your needs --- Wikipedia data is general, but, say, children's stories would be a more niche dataset (and more appropriate / "accurate" if you were solving problems to do with children and/or stories). There are several methods, of course `word2vec` being the most popular, and several packages to help you (e.g. `gensim`).

However, my guess is you would like something that's already out there. The best word embeddings right now are:

- [Numberbatch](https://github.com/commonsense/conceptnet-numberbatch) ('classic' best-in-class ensemble);
- [fastText](https://fasttext.cc/), by Facebook Research (created at the character level --- some words that are out of vocabulary can be "understood" as a result);
- [sense2vec](https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec), by the same guys behind Spacy (created using parts-of-speech (POS) as additional information, with the objective to disambiguate).

The one we are interested in for a quick resolve of your problem is `sense2vec`. You should read the [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1511.06388), but essentially these word embeddings were created using Reddit with additional POS information, and (thus) able to discriminate entities (e.g. nouns) that span multiple words. [This blog post](https://explosion.ai/blog/sense2vec-with-spacy) describes `sense2vec` very well. Here's some code to help you get started (taken from the prior links):

Install:

```
git clone https://github.com/explosion/sense2vec
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip install -e .
sputnik --name sense2vec --repository-url http://index.spacy.io install reddit_vectors
```

Example usage:

```
import sense2vec
model = sense2vec.load()
freq, query_vector = model["onion_rings|NOUN"]
freq2, query_vector2 = model["chicken_nuggets|NOUN"]
print(model.most_similar(query_vector, n=5)[0])
print(model.data.similarity(query_vector, query_vector2))
```

Important note, `sense2vec` **requires** `spacy>=0.100,<0.101`, meaning *it will downgrade your current `spacy` install*, not too much of a problem if you are only loading the `en` model. Also, here are the POS tags used:

```
ADJ ADP ADV AUX CONJ DET INTJ NOUN NUM PART PRON PROPN PUNCT SCONJ SYM VERB X
```

You could use `spacy` for POS and dependency tagging, and then `sense2vec` to determine the similarity of resulting entities. Or, depending on the frequency of your dataset (not too large), you could grab n-grams in descending (n) order, and sequentially check to see if each one is an entity in the `sense2vec` model.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is approach using nltk:

```
from nltk.tokenize import MWETokenizer

tokenizer = MWETokenizer([("artificial","intelligence"), ("data","science")], separator=' ')

tokens = tokenizer.tokenize("I am really interested in data science and artificial intelligence".split())
print(tokens)
```

The output is given as:

```
['I', 'am', 'really', 'interested', 'in', 'data science', 'and', 'artificial intelligence']
```

For more reference you can read [here](http://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html#module-nltk.tokenize.mwe).